# Managing laptop temperature?

Tags: laptop, overheating, fan, temperature, fancontrol

Given my lapop **feels** hotter on Ubuntu than Windows, I've done loads of research to find out if it's harmful and how to control it. I've seen a LOT of guides and forum/askubuntu answers explaining how to monitor the temperature, which is great but doesn't actually do anything else than confirm that my computer is hot. Using sensors and psensors, I did however pinpoint what is hot on my computer and it seems it's the processors. But that being said, every sensor I have has never gotten higher than 66 celcius degrees. I've also found an answer saying that anything under 80 celcius is fine and that there's even a tolerance up to 90.

So I'd like to know if that is true and, if not, how can I make Ubuntu manage the fans more like Windows does?

I've already installed laptop mode and (not at the same time) tlp. But they don't seem to do much.

Here is the result of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    DeviceName: 32
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Oops! Sry I gave you a wrong command. Can you run this one and replace the output. `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

Comment: How old is the laptop, and what processors does it use? Cheers, Al

Comment: @Pilot6 I've updated the answer.

Comment: @heynnema It's an HP EliteBook 8440p from 2010. It has an Intel Core i5 520M / 2.4 GHz.

Comment: This integrated adapter should work well in terms of power management.

Comment: @Pilot6 In other words the recorded temperatures are nothing to be worried about?

Comment: I think it looks OK. There is nothing to worry about. Unity DE loads GPU and that maybe cause some more heat than in Windows.

Comment: Oh I see. I've also found a review of the laptop from 2010 and in one of the cons there: "Underside runs hot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

66 Celsius (~150 degrees) is at the top of the range that I think it should be running, unless you're doing a lot of processor intensive stuff. My i5 idles at around 110-115 degrees.

The reason that I asked about the age and model of the computer, is because if it's in a dusty environment, the cooling fan can have reduced efficiency, or stop working all together. Also, the thermal paste that is in between the processors and it's cooling mechanism needs reapplication if it's old and not conducting as much heat away from the processors as it did when it was new. If you're not willing/able to remove the bottom cover from the laptop to check/clean the cooling fan, at least take a vacuum cleaner with an exhaust port, and with the machine powered off, blow air into the laptop via the vents to try and force out any dust.

Software wise, I'd remove laptop tools and tlp, and try this.

First, make sure that `intel-microcode` is installed. This will make sure that the processors are up to the latest revision. After installation and reboot, in terminal, you can type `dmesg|grep microcode` to see its operation in updating the processors.

Then I'd install `thermald` to see if that helps regulate the temperature better. It comes with a default config file that should work on most machines, but I wrote my own custom config file tailored to my Toshiba i5 laptop. You'll want to read up a little on thermald by typing `man thermald` and `man thermal-conf.xml`, in terminal. You can run thermald manually in `--no-daemon` mode to watch if it's doing the right thing, or as a basis for writing your own custom config file.

Comment: Great! Let us know the results. Also, please vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Cheers, Al

Comment: Can you give details? Did you get any dust out of the machine? What temps are you running now? Did you see the CPU's microcode get updated? Cheers, Al